# self.window not working inside view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uistatusbar

For iOS 7, I had status bar problem. For that I solved it by using below code in Appdelegate

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
    self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
}
```

All is working perfectly.

Only it gives problem while taking photo.

When I open camera or photo gallery, I still see status bar and because of that I see half of the navigation title as shown below.

[image]

Any idea how can I overcome this error?

The problems are :

1. Photo Gallery/ Camera comes like above image
2. If I click cancel, my view is shifted 20px up automatically.

Comment: @sathiamoorthy : code pls... I don't get what u meant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this problem wih one of my project. We didn't even have the xib for many classes. So all I could do is reset the frame once again in the delegate functions.

```
   [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                              completion:^{
                                                  [self.navigationController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.navigationController.view.frame.origin.x, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height)];
                                              }];
```

I put this in the finish/cancel delegate methods of photo/camera picket, mail picker.

Comment: Why do you need to reset when you can tell the navigation controller what is its rootviewcontroller and so on.. The frame will be set by itself. I have done the same thing with out any reset.

Comment: Thank u... Thank u... Thank u... Thank u... Thank u... Thank u... Thank u... Thank u... Thank u...  Why you didn't met me yesterday ;) I was wasting 4 hours on it... thanks Man...

Comment: @Suresh : I am facing now one problem... When I add some photo and try to add new photo again, all mess goes... when I tries to upload second image and click cancel or upload image, view gets resetted.. all goes to top

Comment: You have to place the code in the imagePickerControllerDidCancel also.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of:

```
self.window
```

Use this:

```
[[self view] window]
```

Try Like this:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.view.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
    self.view.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.view.window.frame.size.width,self.view.window.frame.size.height-20);
    self.view.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.window.frame.size.width, self.view.window.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: but you have mentioned that it is not working inside view controller,as per the heading of question.

Comment: sorry for that... see my updated question... i hope you got what is problem... if not, let me know, I will update question

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using the UINavigationController. There is nothing to do with the frame nor to do something with the Status Bar, If you are using UINavigationController. Please prefer the below code to set the UINavigationController along with Status bar set up. Else you can display the code, Will help you fix this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ExViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    self.mainViewNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewNavigation;


    [self.window addSubview:self.mainViewNavigation.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The answer is for setting the navigationController's rootviewcontroller and so on. No matter where ever you use it